# Mocking constructor using PowerMockito doesn't work

Tags: java, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I want to test a method which creates an object of another class using it's parameterized constructor. Even though I've mocked the constructor of MyClass, it makes the third party library which is in constructor implementation and results in the error. I'm using Mockito/PowerMockito.

```
public class MyClass{

   private MyObj obj;

   MyClass (String profile)
   {
      //some 3rd party library call
      obj = thridPartyLib.someMethod(profile);       
   }

   public String someMethod(){
     return obj.someExternalCall();
   }

}
```

Class which I want to test

```
public class ClassTobeTested{

   public void execute(){
       //some code
       // ......
       MyClass myClass = new MyClass(profile);
       myclass.someMethod();
   }
}
```

What I tried so far - `classUnderTest.execute()` ends up calling the `thridPartyLib.someMethod(profile);` which is part of MyClass constructor.

```
 @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
 @PrepareForTest(MyClass.class)
 public class ClassTobeTestedTest {

     private MyClass mockMyClass;
     private ClassTobeTested classUnderTest;


    @Before
    public void init() {    
       classUnderTest = new ClassTobeTested();
       mockMyClass = PowerMockito.mock(MyClass.class);  
    }

   @Test
   public void testExecute(){

      PowerMockito.whenNew(MyClass.class)
                 .withArguments(Mockito.any())
                 .thenReturn(mockMyClass);

      classUnderTest.execute();     
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you instantiating the variable profile?

Answer (score 4):

Your code will work only if you are working with a spy or mock of  classUnderTest.  Try this. This should work

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( {MyClass.class, ClassTobeTested.class })
public class ClassTobeTestedTest {

  private MyClass mockMyClass;
  private ClassTobeTested classUnderTest;


  @Before
  public void init() {
    classUnderTest = spy(new ClassTobeTested());
    mockMyClass = PowerMockito.mock(MyClass.class);
  }

  @Test
  public void testExecute() throws Exception {

    PowerMockito.whenNew(MyClass.class)
        .withArguments(Mockito.any())
        .thenReturn(mockMyClass);

    classUnderTest.execute();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The pain might suggest another approach.  Consider injecting a Factory into `ClassTobeTested` which knows how to create an instance of `MyObj`.  For example:

```
class MyObjFactory {
   MyObj create(String profile) {
       return new MyClass(profile);
  }
}
```

then

```
public class ClassTobeTested {
    private final MyObjFactory factory;

    public  ClassTobeTested(MyObjFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

   public void execute(){
       //some code
       // ......
      // MyClass myClass = new MyClass(profile);
      MyClass myClass = factory.create(profile);
      myclass.someMethod();
   }
}
```

so the unit test becomes simpler with only having to mock the Factory and have it return a mocked `MyClass` instance.  Then it's simple to verify `myclass.someMethod()` was invoked as expected.